# function inside a function, python recursive on a list

Tags: python, recursion

```
def minimizeMaximumPair(lst):
    lst.sort()

    def compute(aList):
        if len(aList) != 0:
            return [(aList[0], lst[len(aList) - 1])].extend(compute(aList[1:len(aList) - 1]))
        return []

    return compute(lst)
```

When I get the the last recursion step I get an

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I tried returning nothing, and a []

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `list.extend` which returns `None`, you can use `list.__iadd__`

`__iadd__` also extends the list inplace, but returns the `list` afterward

if you have an aversion to using special methods, you can use `iadd` from the `operator` module

```
from operator import iadd

...

def compute(aList):
    if len(aList) != 0:
        return iadd([(aList[0], aList[-1])], compute(aList[1: -1]))
    return []
```

Comment: That's kind of pointless. Why should we have to call a 'special' method? This issue is more a misunderstanding with the behaviour of the used methods.

Comment: @Zizouz212, not really. If you're writing functional style code, you need to know about this, otherwise you'll duplicate code that's already part of the language.

Comment: I changed the recursive call to simplier but using your solution : iadd([(aList[0], aList[-1])], compute(aList[1:-1]))

Comment: @MaximeRoussin-Bélanger, cool I updated my answer. Now - you still are still making a partial copy with the `aList[1: -1]`. If you need more performance, you should look at passing extra parameters for the first and last index instead of actually slicing up the list.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is when you call `.extend()`.

Your `compute` function tries to return the value of `.extend()`, which is `None`. Similar to `.sort()`, `.extend()` modifies the object itself, rather than returning a modified copy of the object. This is known as mutability. Here's some working code:

```
def compute(aList):
    if len(aList) != 0:
        out = [(aList[0], lst[len(aList) - 1])]
        out.extend(compute(aList[1:len(aList) - 1]))
        return out
    return []
```

Comment: I guess I could go backward because : <not copied>.extend(<copied>)  right?

Comment: @MaximeRoussin-Bélanger Yep, you should be able to.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `extend` is a function that doesn't return anything, it simply changes the list in-place. A possible solution is to use `+` instead:

```
return [(aList[0], lst[len(aList) - 1])] + compute(aList[1:len(aList) - 1])
```

Comment: This causes the first list to be copied each time instead of just extending the existing list

Comment: True, but is also the cleanest solution.

Comment: Perhaps, but that attitude - when laid layer upon layer upon layer - gives us a lot of the slowness in large programs